# Admitting to a misdemeanor crime on an "official" police application

Tags: united-states, police, admissibility

When someone wants to apply to become a police officer, one question on the form is whether or not they have committed a crime or were present when a crime was committed. If they say yes and detail the crime committed, and the statute of limitations has not passed, is it possible the individual would be arrested and convicted of the crime? Could the form be taken as an "official government document," allowing the answer to considered tantamount to a confession even for a misdemeanor?

Comment: Related: ["Garrity v. New Jersey"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garrity_v._New_Jersey), Wikipedia.

Comment: For what it's worth, on a general job application they're more likely ask if the applicant has been "convicted" of a crime. Unless they are trying to be extra sneaky I suppose...

Comment: Is that really how the question is worded?  I have completed applications for background checks for top secret clearances in the military, and for airline pilot.  The closest to that I think I've ever seen to that wording is asking if I had been arrested or charged.  Certainly convictions are fair game to ask about,  but "have you ever been present" is a pretty high standard!  Who has never been to an underage kegger?!  (even if you didn't drink you would answer yes)  I would invoke Garrity vs New Jersey as well as the 5th amendment and decline to answer that one.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible. If you say e.g. "On March 12 2021 I stole a steak from the grocery store at the corner of Smith St. and Wesson Ave.", that is a confession. It is voluntary and not coerced (you're not required to apply for the job), so it is admissible. It is extremely unlikely that there is any insulating provision in the job-application process ("information obtained via applying for this job will never be used against you in a court of law"). Whether or not you would actually be arrested and tried depends on the circumstances (basically, is it "worth it" to them to prosecute you). Also, what you say in the "explanation" box matters, so I gave you a clear confession to criminal culpability. Something like "I was at the store when some dude shot a lady" isn't a confession to committing a crime, it more satisfies the full-disclosure requirement.

Comment: The analysis on whether the confession was coerced seems a bit thin. A person isn't required to confess when they're being held without an attorney, but we still treat it as coercion. This is a long ways off, and the bottom-line conclusion may be correct, but it feels a bit more like guesswork than anything else.

Comment: @bdb484 I think that the analysis about voluntariness as opposed to coercion is almost surely correct and for the right reasons. The inquiry on voluntariness generally hinges on whether you are in custody at the time, and if any threat tantamount to extortion or duress is present. A job application context presents none of these circumstances.

Comment: Worth noting that lying on the application will be grounds for termination when the truth comes out - these questions are generally honesty tests and minor offences will not usually rule you out.

Comment: Might be worth commenting on ["_Garrity vs. New Jersey, 385 U.S. 493 (1967)_"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garrity_v._New_Jersey).  While that case apparently dealt with someone who already had a job (rather than a job-applicant), it'd seem related.

Comment: @ohwilleke If someone doesn't have any good alternative job available, making something a requirement of a job requirement certainly is duress, at least in the ordinary meaning, although there may be some more specific definition that it doesn't satisfy.

Comment: @Acccumulation yes, an actual legal one. That scenario is probably not duress unless you can establish (give or take) that you would actually unavoidably die or be grievously injured if you didn't get that specific job, that lying on the application would actually help, and that no legal alternative was available to you. And in some places, not even then — you would need someone to have maliciously *put* you in that situation, not gotten into it through your own mistakes or sheer bad luck.

Comment: @hobbs Cite for that being a legal definition of "duress"?

Comment: @Acccumulation https://www.justia.com/criminal/defenses/duress/ is reasonable.

Comment: Regarding "_duress_":  ["Garrity vs. New Jersey"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garrity_v._New_Jersey) was a 5-4 decision.  The majority-opinion argued that was duress was clearly present; by sharp contrast, the main dissenting-opinion argued that duress was clearly absent.  So, it might be a historically controversial issue.